# how to print not mapped value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, entity-framework-4

I am using complicated SQL queries, i have to use SqlQuery ... in simple way:

MODEL:

```
public class C
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public float Value { get; set; }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
IEnumerable<C> results = db.C.SqlQuery(@"SELECT ID, ATAN(-45.01) as Value from C);
return View(results.ToList());
```

VIEW:

```
@model IEnumerable<C>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
}
```

and the result for item.Value is NULL.

So my question is , how can i print the computed value from SQL Query ?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would conclude from the fact that `Value` is 0 that EF doesn't map returned columns to properties that are not mapped in the model.

What you could try as an alternative is to define a helper type...

```
public class CHelper
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then query into this type and copy the values to your entity afterwards:

```
IEnumerable<C> results = db.Database.SqlQuery<CHelper>(
    @"SELECT ID, ATAN(-45.01) as Value from C")
    .Select(ch => new C
    {
        ID = ch.ID,
        Value = ch.Value
    });
```

(Normally in a LINQ-to-Entities query you cannot project into an entity with `Select`. But I believe that the `Select` in the example above does not affect the database query and is LINQ-to-Objects in memory, so it should be allowed. I am not sure, though.)

Note that the `results` collection is not attached to and tracked by the context, but I guess you don't need it anyway for a GET request to render a view.

Of course you could create your view directly based on the `CHelper` class as view model and omit the conversion into the `C` entity.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't worked, for code  
return View(results.ToList());   i recieved:  
    The cast to value type 'Single' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.  

and for return View(results); i have all nulls

Comment: I am sorry for multiple comments. The lambda expression `ch` is null in debug mode. The database didnt return any value ? or the query wasnt send to database ?   i feel that the solution is very close. please help.

Comment: `public class CHelper
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public float? Value { get; set; }
}` 
`Value` was `null` in one record. i set the value as `nullable`. now its working. Thank you Slauma.